# PDB alias in commands

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm trying to set up some automated debugging in pdb. I want to be able to specify some complicated code in an aliased commands section. The following works:

```
# -- .pdbrc (working)
alias set_bp b 270 ;; commands ;; silent ;; print('hello') ;; end
```

However when I specify an alias inside the commands, the interpreter bugs out

```
# -- .pdbrc (not working)
alias do_print print('%1')
alias set_bp b 270 ;; commands ;; silent ;; do_print hello ;; end

# -- PDB

(Pdb) set_bp
Breakpoint 1 at script.py:270
(com)                <---- Should go back to (Pdb), I have to type end
```

How can I get aliases inside commands to work correctly?
As an aside, is there any way I can split an alias into multiple lines?